# Get a Process objet in C# from CreateProcessWithTokenW

Tags: c#, windows, process

For the need of my application i create a process with CreateProcessWithTokenW https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithtokenw
This help me run a process under the desktop user because my application is run under the Admin User

Before i use C# process to handle my process and get output ect...

How can i Get the process after create it with CreateProcessWithTokenW ? Their is some IntPtr in StartUPINFO that i get back but i don't find how to get the process with this.

My struct is

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public Int32 cb;
            public string lpReserved;
            public string lpDesktop;
            public string lpTitle;
            public Int32 dwX;
            public Int32 dwY;
            public Int32 dwXSize;
            public Int32 dwYSize;
            public Int32 dwXCountChars;
            public Int32 dwYCountChars;
            public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
            public Int32 dwFlags;
            public Int16 wShowWindow;
            public Int16 cbReserved2;
            public IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }
```

i kinda understand i got some Ptr to ouput input ect... but i don't get how to get my process back any ideA?

Comment: handle to process inside [`PPROCESS_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-process_information) - this is *out* parameter. the `STARTUPINFO` is *in* only parameter - no sense look here. and based on your task, you need call `CreateProcessAsUserW` instead `CreateProcessWithTokenW`

Comment: I kinda follow a the microsoft documentation https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaron_margosis/2009/06/06/faq-how-do-i-start-a-program-as-the-desktop-user-from-an-elevated-app/ but its probably a bit outdated.

And yes i just suceed with [PROCESS_INFORMATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-process_information)
So gonna answer myself and mark it as solved thank for the fast answer

Answer (score 0):

I wasnt looking in the good place. Now y use the PROCESS_INFORMATION that my methode send back
Inside their is a process Id that i can get back with this simple code

```
var res = ProcessHelper.RunAsDesktopUser(fileName, opt);
var process = Process.GetProcessById(res.dwProcessId);
```

I have tested it and it work perfectly fine.

Comment: you not need `GetProcessById` because you already have process handle inside `PROCESS_INFORMATION`

Comment: I need it because after i use some C# event associate to my process i just get back the process i create to interact with it

Comment: My code use some feature with the C# class Process so i'm not sure what you mean by having the process handle but i need to have my class objet so i cna keep my old code.